# TeX-FAQ: Non-letters in macro names - special-command generator

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I had a look at TeX-FAQ on [Non-letters in macro names](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linmacnames) and tried to implement the approach #2. It looks like I'm missing something. When trying to refer later to the new commands the result is not what I expected.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\DefineNode}[2]
{
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname node-#1\endcsname{#2}
}
\newcommand{\GetNode}[1]{\csname node-#1\endcsname}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def \intra {1}
  \def \inter {3}

  % Calculate values
  \foreach \x [count=\xi from 0] in {a,...,c}
  {
    \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpi{\xi * \inter}
    \DefineNode{n\x.0}{\tmpi}

    \pgfmathsetmacro\tmpii{\xi * \inter + \intra}
    \DefineNode{n\x.1}{\tmpii}

    \message{\GetNode{n\x.0} ^^J}
    \message{\GetNode{n\x.1} ^^J}
  }

  % Doing something with them later
  \foreach \x in {a,...,c}
  {
    \message{\GetNode{n\x.0} ^^J}
    \message{\GetNode{n\x.1} ^^J}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

```
0.0
1.0
3.0
4.0
6.0
7.0
\node-na.0
\node-na.1
\node-nb.0
\node-nb.1
\node-nc.0
\node-nc.1
```

Instead of repeating numbers twice.

EDIT: Solved the group issue by forcing names to be globals.

```
\newcommand{\DefineNode}[2]
{
  \globaldefs=1\relax
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname node-#1\endcsname{#2}
}
```

Result currently:

```
0.0
1.0
3.0
4.0
6.0
7.0
6.0
7.0
6.0
7.0
6.0
7.0
```

Instead of repeating first 6 lines, now 6.0 and 7.0 are repeated. This is due to using only two macros \tmpi and \tmpii. How to solve this?

Comment: Maybe TikZ `\foreach` defines a group? In this case the definition would be local to the body of `\foreach`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: According to http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75152/56821 TikZ \foreach defines two groups. Edited the question to solve the group issue.

Comment: No, ***don't*** do `\globaldefs=1`. Use `\expandafter\gdef\csname node-#1\endcsname{#2}` instead.

Comment: You mean like this? 

    \gdef \DefineNode#1#2
    {
      \expandafter\gdef\csname node-#1\endcsname{#2}
    }

It will produce:

    0.0
    1.0
    3.0
    4.0
    6.0
    7.0
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    \node-na.0 ->\tmpi

Comment: Don't modify `\globaldefs`! `\newcommand` is a macro which does temporary assignments that don't need to be done globally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A feature of `\foreach` is that it performs each cycle in a group; its main purpose was to add paths or nodes to a `tikzpicture` being built and this operation is indeed global.

Doing `\globaldefs=1` is *not* a good workaround, because `\newcommand` performs several assignments that you really don't want to be global.

You can look at [`\global\renewcommand` equivalent of `\global\def`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51733/global-renewcommand-equivalent-of-global-def) for a `\gnewcommand` that doesn't require `\globaldefs=1`. However, in the case at hand, a simpler

```
\newcommand{\DefineNode}[2]{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname node-#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
```

seems sufficient. You need `\xdef` in order to expand `\tmpi` and `\tmpii`.

You won't be warned about redefining the same control sequence. If you really need this feature, then

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand\@nameedef[1]{\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\DefineNode}[2]{%
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\expandafter{\csname node-#1\endcsname}{%
    \global\@nameedef\node-#1}{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

is what you're looking for. Again an expanded definition is necessary.

Comment: I'm must be missing something.
First one produces:
    0.0
    1.0
    3.0
    4.0
    6.0
    7.0
    ! Undefined control sequence.
    \node-na.0 ->\tmpi
Second one produces:
    ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

Comment: @karu You have to use `\xdef`, of course, so `\tmpi` is expanded. With `\globaldefs=1` you got no error, but wrong output. I have modified my answer to reflect this.