# How to perform a \global\renewenvironment

Tags: macros, environments, grouping

I need to execute a `\renewenvironment` within a group. Using `\global\renewenvironment` is not sufficient.

What changes do I need to make to the `\DisableMyEnvironment` macro in the MWE below so as to achieve the equivalent of `\global\renewenvironment`?

Currently, the MWE yields:

[image]

Once this is working as desired, the second line in blue should be in black.

### Notes:

- There are two test cases. The default one is within a `\foreach` and commenting out `\def\ForeachTestCase{}` uses a simple group.

### References:

- [\global\renewcommand equivalent of \global\def](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51733/4301).

### Code:

```
\def\ForeachTestCase{}%

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newenvironment{MyEnvironment}[1][blue]{%
    \begingroup
        \color{#1}%
}{%
    \endgroup
}%

\newcommand*{\DisableMyEnvironment}{%
    %% How make this global??
    \renewenvironment{MyEnvironment}[1][]{}{}%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyTestText}[1]{%
    Some before text

    \begin{MyEnvironment}
        This should be in #1.
    \end{MyEnvironment}

    Some after text%
}

\begin{document}

\MyTestText{blue}

%\DisableMyEnvironment% <-- This works, but want it to work when used in a group as follows
\ifdefined\ForeachTestCase
    \foreach \x in {1,...,3} {%
        \IfStrEqCase{\x}{%
            {1}{}%
            {2}{\DisableMyEnvironment}%
            {3}{}%
        }%
    }
\else
    \begingroup
        \DisableMyEnvironment
    \endgroup
\fi

\medskip\par
\MyTestText{black}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know your real application, but one option is to use `\aftergroup\DisableMyEnvironment`. I don't know if this will do what you want, though.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Yep, that works fine in the MWE. It doesn't seem to work in my actual use case (which is within a `\fpreach`). Will look into it and try to figure it out.

Comment: I read somewhere that a `\foreach` does its thing inside two grouping levels, so `\aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\DisableMyEnvironment` should do. Not the prettiest code there is though :P

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik: Yep that was it. Thanks. You should post an answer as that seems to be the cleanest approach and does not require dealing with both the `\environement ` and `\endenvironment` separately.

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but would work:
`{\let\def\gdef\renewenvironment{MyEnvironment}[1][]{}{}}` and it's global!

Comment: A more sensible example is needed. I don't think you really want to do that `\foreach`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a dummy (or alternate) environment in the global scope (preamble), here, `XEnvironment`, and then in the `\DisableMyEnvironment` macro, globally reassign by way of

```
\global\let\MyEnvironment\XEnvironment%
\global\let\endMyEnvironment\endXEnvironment%
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{XEnvironment}[1][]{}{}%
\newenvironment{MyEnvironment}[1][blue]{%
    \begingroup
        \color{#1}%
}{%
    \endgroup
}%

\newcommand*{\DisableMyEnvironment}{%
    %% How make this global??
    \global\let\MyEnvironment\XEnvironment%
    \global\let\endMyEnvironment\endXEnvironment%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyTestText}[1]{%
    Some before text

    \begin{MyEnvironment}
        This should be in #1.
    \end{MyEnvironment}

    Some after text%
}

\begin{document}

\MyTestText{blue}

%\DisableMyEnvironment% <-- This works, but want it to work when used in a group as follows
\begingroup
    \DisableMyEnvironment
\endgroup

\medskip\par
\MyTestText{black}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was initially opposed to using two separate commands to disable _and_ define a new dummy environment, but then this does seem simpler to use as then you don't have to worry about which grouping level you are in (works fine for both the _original_ text case and the new `\foreach` case.

Comment: @PeterGrill I am not sure why using 2 commands should be an issue.  For example, to use a changed catcode in a macro, the catcode has to be changed prior to the macro definition, so that it takes effect when the macro's argument gets tokenized.  While cumbersome, nobody really complains that the catcode change *should* occur inside the macro definition.  In summary, it's all in the preamble...it's not like you have to define things on the fly.

Comment: Agreed. I attempted to say that with the "initially".. Hiding it in the preamble is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: First approach didn't seem to work with optional arguments.

**Edit 2**: Found an easier way using `\globaldefs`:

### Final answer:

In spirit of answering how to do a `\renewenvironment` global:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \newenvironment{test}{HELLO}{WORLD}
  \bgroup
    \globaldefs=1
    \renewenvironment{test}[1][world]{foo #1}{bar}
  \egroup
  \begin{test}[hello]
  \end{test}
\end{document}
```

### Second answer:

Two commands loosely inspired by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`: `\makerenewglobal` and `\makerenewlocal`. When `\makerenewglobal` is called, `\renewenvironment` do only global definitions. If `\makerenewlocal` is called, it does the oposite: makes all `\renewenvironment`-definitions local.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@local@newenv\@newenv
\long\def\@global@newenv#1#2#3#4{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}{\global\expandafter\let\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname}{\relax}
  {\let\def\gdef\expandafter\new@command\csname #1\endcsname#2{#3}}%
  \l@ngrel@x\expandafter\gdef\csname end#1\endcsname{#4}%
}
\gdef\makerenewglobal{\global\let\@newenv\@global@newenv}
\gdef\makerenewlocal{\global\let\@newenv\@local@newenv}
\begin{document}
  \newenvironment{test}{HELLO}{WORLD}
  \bgroup\makerenewglobal
    \renewenvironment{test}[1][world]{foo #1}{bar}
  \egroup
  \begin{test}[hello]
  \end{test}
\end{document}
```

#### First answer:

In spirit of semi-generality; a command, `\makeenvglobal{theenv}`, that makes a environment global:

```
\documentclass{article}
\gdef\makeenvglobal#1{%
  \global\expandafter\expandafter\let\csname #1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \global\expandafter\expandafter\let\csname end#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#1\endcsname
}
\begin{document}
  \newenvironment{test}{HELLO}{WORLD}
  \bgroup
    \renewenvironment{test}{foo}{bar}
    \makeenvglobal{test}
  \egroup
  \begin{test}
  \end{test}
\end{document}
```

prints `foo bar`

Comment: Does this need to be altered to handle the case where the environment having an optional parameter (as in the MWE)?

Comment: @PeterGrill Oh. Yeah somethings going on. Give me a minute!

Comment: @PeterGrill See new answer!

Comment: Yep, revised answer works.

Answer (score 1):

As requested :)

I read <s>somewhere</s> [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75152/134574) that `\foreach` executes its commands inside two groups. You can check this statement with this (requires e-TeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0}{\the\currentgrouplevel}
\end{document}
```

which will print `2` :)

If you want to do a definition outside the scope of this `\foreach`, then you can use a couple of `\aftergroup`s. In your case you want to run `\DisableMyEnvironment` (one token) outside of two grouping levels.

If you do `\aftergroup\DisableMyEnvironment`, this will insert `\DisableMyEnvironment` after the first group (one `\aftergroup` per token). To make it reach the second level, you have to `\aftergroup` that (two tokens), so `\aftergroup\aftergroup` `\aftergroup\DisableMyEnvironment`.

Have in mind that **this is not a global assignment**, rather just local to another grouping level. If you are in, say, a third grouping level, the changes will be restored after the third one ends.

---

Just a few days ago I was doing something (can't remember what though --- or can I?) and was using a very long chain of `\aftergroup`s, and was getting it wrong because I was missing one or another. What did I do? An even longer chain of `\expandafter` =D

I made a (probably suboptimal) macro `\afterNgroups{<N>}{<token-list>}` that inserts the `<token-list>` after `<N>` groups:

```
\makeatletter
\def\afterNgroups#1#2{%
  \count@\z@
  \toks@{#2}%
  \loop
  \ifnum\count@<#1 %
    \toks2{}%
    \expandafter\@tfor\expandafter\tkn\expandafter:\expandafter=\the\toks@\do{%
      \toks2
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
       {\expandafter\the\expandafter\toks\expandafter2\expandafter\aftergroup\tkn}}%
      \toks@\expandafter{\the\toks2}%
    \advance\count@\@ne
  \repeat
  \the\toks@}
\makeatother
```

you can use this macro for your case with `\afterNgroups{2}{\DisableMyEnvironment}`. It apparently works for trivial cases. Didn't test it extensively though.