# \global \newcommand in align environment

Tags: macros, amsmath

I want to use `\newcommand` within an `align` environment. Furthermore, I need the newly defined command outside of the align environment. While this is easy for the case of `\def` as I can simply prefix it by `\global`. This solution does not work for `\newcommand`. However there are solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448220), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51750/22187), and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51751/22187). All of these solution work well within an `equation` environment. However, they fail within a `align` environment. In the following MWE I have commented out the failing commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51750/22187
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\gnewcommand{\g@star@or@long\gnew@command}
\def\grenewcommand{\g@star@or@long\grenew@command}
\def\g@star@or@long#1{\@ifstar{\let\l@ngrel@x\global#1}{\def\l@ngrel@x{\long\global}#1}}
\def\gnew@command#1{\@testopt{\@gnewcommand#1}0}
\def\@gnewcommand#1[#2]{\kernel@ifnextchar [{\@gxargdef#1[#2]}{\@argdef#1[#2]}}
\let\@gxargdef\@xargdef
\patchcmd{\@gxargdef}{\def}{\gdef}{}{}
\let\grenew@command\renew@command
\patchcmd{\grenew@command}{\new@command}{\gnew@command}{}{}
\makeatother

% taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51751/22187
\makeatletter
\def\reset@l@texglobal{\let\l@texglobal\relax}
\reset@l@texglobal
\def\latexglobal{\let\l@texglobal\global}
\long\def\@yargd@f#1#2{%
  \def\reserved@a##1#1##2##{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter#2\reserved@b##1#1%
  }%
  \afterassignment\reset@l@texglobal
  \l@texglobal\l@ngrel@x\reserved@a 0##1##2##3##4##5##6##7##8##9###1%
}    
\long\def\@xargdef#1[#2][#3]#4{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{%
    \l@texglobal\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\@protected@testopt\expandafter#1\csname\string#1\endcsname{#3}%
    }
    \expandafter\@yargdef\csname\string#1\endcsname\tw@{#2}{#4}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

% testing functions    
\newcommand\GlobalDef[1]{
  \global\expandafter\def\csname GlobalDef#1\endcsname{GlobalDef#1}
}    
\newcommand\GlobaldefsNewcommand[1]{
  \globaldefs=1
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname GlobaldefsNewcommand#1\endcsname{GlobaldefsNewcommand#1}
  \globaldefs=0
}    
\newcommand\Gnewcommand[1]{
  \expandafter\gnewcommand\csname Gnewcommand#1\endcsname{Gnewcommand#1}
}    
\newcommand\LatexglobalNewcommand[1]{
  \latexglobal\expandafter\newcommand\csname LatexglobalNewcommand#1\endcsname{LatexglobalNewcommand#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\GlobalDef{Equation}
\GlobaldefsNewcommand{Equation}
\Gnewcommand{Equation}
\LatexglobalNewcommand{Equation}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\GlobalDef{Align}
% \GlobaldefsNewcommand{Align} % does not work
% \Gnewcommand{Align} % does not work
% \LatexglobalNewcommand{Align} % does not work
\end{align}

\GlobalDefEquation{} \GlobalDefAlign{}

\GlobaldefsNewcommandEquation{} % \GlobaldefsNewcommandAlign{}

\GnewcommandEquation{} % \GnewcommandAlign{}

\LatexglobalNewcommandEquation{} % \LatexglobalNewcommandAlign{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the reason for doing definitions inside `align`? You should be aware that `align` scans its input twice, so a `\gnewcommand` will fail at the second pass.

Comment: you can use `\ifmeasuring@` to detect in which phase you are, but doing \newcommand in align sounds very odd.

Comment: I am playing around with defining my mathematical objects as macros the first time they appear and subsequent occurrences link then to the definition. If I implemented this in the header it would become quickly hard to maintain.

Comment: Why you does not use simply `\gdef`? I never used newcmmand, only `\def` of `\gdef`. It is much more simply and straithforward.

Comment: There are many text shorthand of one to two character length. It is very easy to override them accidentally by math definitions. This may work well most of the time if you stick to the English language, but can have nasty side effects in e.g. the bibliography. Hence I want to know what I override by using renewcommand.