# Input multi files at one time by \foreach

Tags: input, foreach, loops

I have several files in the sub-folder `./tmp` -- "a.tex" whose content is `\def\aaa{aaa}`, "b.tex" whose content is `\def\bbb{bbb}.

Then I input them to my main doc at one time by `\foreach`, as the following code tries, but it fails to work, and causes error message  `Undefined control sequence.`.

What shall I do?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\foreach \x in {a.tex,b.tex}{
  \input{tmp/\x}
  }
\begin{document}
\aaa\bbb
\end{document}
```

Comment: Foreach was define macro in a group, you need `\gdef`.

Comment: How to `\gdef` \input? Or are there any better methods than `\foreach`?

Comment: `\gdef\aaa{aaa}`, `\gdef\bbb{bbb}`

Comment: Oh, I see. And for `\newcommand`, how to make it global?

Comment: `\newcommand` was use `\def`, you could use `\let\olddef\def` `\let\def\gdef` `\newcommand...` `\let\def\olddef`

Comment: I don't want to redefine `\def` as it relates many other things. It seems that `\foreach` in my example is not a good idea. Any other better methods for this question?

Comment: Maybe `\global\let\aaa\aaa`. There isn't really a non-hacky way I guess.

Comment: [macros - \global\renewcommand equivalent of \global\def - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51733/global-renewcommand-equivalent-of-global-def)

Comment: There are many things and definations in those files which will be included in my main doc. I don't want to modify them one by one. So I have to give up `\foreach` and look forward to other better ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way around the problem is to use `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\multiinput}{O{.}m}
 {% #1 = common prefix, default . for the current directory
  % #2 = list of file names
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \input{#1/##1} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\multiinput[tmp]{a,b}

\fooA

\fooB

\end{document}
```

In the subdirectory `tmp` I put

```
% file a.tex
\newcommand{\fooA}{A}

\fooA
```

and

```
% file b.tex
\newcommand{\fooB}{B}

\fooB
```

Compiling the main file above produces

[image]

With `\foreach` every cycle in the loop is processed inside a group, which is the reason why definitions inside the `\input` files don't survive. The proposed solution uses no grouping.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way around the problem is to use OpTeX. It provides ts own expandable `\foreach` without inserting groups:

```
\foreach{a.tex}{b.tex}\do{\input{tmp/#1}}
```

If you are not using OpTeX then you can create your own macro using TeX primitives:

```
\def\forfiles#1{\ifx\relax#1\else \input{tmp/#1}\expandafter\forfiles\fi}
\forfiles{a.tex}{b.tex}\relax
```

You need not any `expl3`. The proposed solution uses no grouping.

Comment: Elegant solution! Thank you. And how to modify it to make `tmp` as an optional argument?

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to `latex3`. This is a method to manipulating items in token lists.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{a.tex}
\def\aaa{aaa}
\newcommand{\ddd}{ddd}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{b.tex}
\def\bbb{bbb}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{c.tex}
\def\ccc{ccc}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \tl__myfiles
\tl_set:Nn \tl__myfiles {{a.tex}{b.tex}{c.tex}}
\tl_map_variable:NNn \tl__myfiles \x {\input{\x}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd
\end{document}
```

Comment: By convention it's called `latex3`, not `latex3e`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ changed