# Allow special character (underscore) in loop (using pgffor)

Tags: errors, symbols, foreach, loops, pgffor

I would like to allow special characters (in my case, an underscore) to be displayed in a loop.

Say I have this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\foreach \g in {ab, cd}{
    \g
}

\end{document}
```

This works, and prints `ab cd`.

However, if I instead tweak `cd` in the loop to be `c_d`, I get an error.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\foreach \g in {ab, c_d}{
    \g
}

\end{document}
```

Error:

```
Missing $ inserted.
```

Now, normally, I would just write `c_d` as `c\_d`, but I can't do so given the loop. Is there a workaround? Perhaps a function that allows the special characters to be displayed? Note that in my application, I would like to be able to print `c_d` in a figure caption or in a subsection.

Comment: Why can't you use `c\_d` in the loop? `\foreach \g in {ab, c\_d}{ \g}` works for me.

Comment: Admittedly, that does work for my MWE. But in my actual application I also need to open a file based on `\g`. I get this error if I replace `c_d` with `c\_d`: `Missing endcsname inserted <to be read again> protect`

Comment: Then we need more information on what you are trying to do. [`\foreach` might not be the right tool for the job to begin with.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/647795) It will also depend on what “opening a file” entails.

Comment: That's fair, and don't feel like you need to answer questions I didn't ask! (By opening a file, I just mean `\includegraphics`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `_` as part of a filename for `\includegraphics` works inside the body of `\foreach` without extra work.

Typesetting that name will be trouble but the `url` package can handle that for you. Despite it name it is also

> intended for formatting email addresses, hypertext links, directories/paths, etc.

You can use the `\urlstyle` command to change the font of the “url”: `tt` (default), `rm`, `sf` or `same`.

Here, I have used `\DeclareUrlCommand` so that you have a purposeful `\mygraphicsfile` command that acts just as `\url` but with the same font as the surrounding text (if that's what you want).

The `\expandafter`s are needed so that the package doesn't assume `\g` to be the url/filename.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\DeclareUrlCommand\mygraphicsfile{\urlstyle{same}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \g in {ab, c_d}{%
  Name \expandafter\mygraphicsfile\expandafter{\g}: \includegraphics[width=3cm]{\g}
  \par
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: You might be able to use `\_` in the loop when you do `\renewcommand*\_{_}` only for the `\includegraphics`.